# subtracting one time from another in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a variable [ Dim mytime = "12:30:00 AM" ]

i want to subtract mytime from TimeOfDay and i also want to get the difference as a integer value... how should i do that..

i have added the following code

```
Dim mytime = DateTime.Parse("1:16:00 AM")
Dim result = TimeOfDay - mytime

dim finalresult = result.Seconds
```

but it is giving me negative values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy:

First, convert the `myTime` to a `DateTime` – either directly:

```
Dim myTime = #12:30:00 AM#
```

Or by parsing a string:

```
Dim myTime = DateTime.Parse("12:30:00 AM")

Dim result = DateTime.TimeOfDay - myTime
```

But you won’t get an integer – how should this work? What should the integer represent? Instead, you get a `TimeSpan`.

If you need to have the difference in seconds, you can extract that, of course:

```
Dim differenceInSeconds = result.Seconds
```

Same goes for minutes or any other component.

Comment: but it is giving me the following result
Operator '-' is not defined for types 'String' and 'Date'.

Comment: @testkhan: Why String? I though you wanted to subtract two `DateTime`s. Ah, I get it … see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim difference As TimeSpan = DateTime.TimeOfDay - DateTime.Parse(mytime)
```

Comment: The result of subtracting two `DateTime` s is a `TimeSpan`, not a `DateTime` itself.

Comment: @Red-nosed unicorn Whoops...my mistake. Updated, fixed the order of subtraction, and got rid of my C#-y semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think you're looking for the total number of seconds, so

```
Dim differenceInSeconds = result.Seconds
```

should read:

```
Dim differenceInSeconds = result.TotalSeconds
```